# Wine Steam Error: Unhandled exception: unimplemented function x3daudio1_7.dll.X3DAudioInitialize called in 32-bit code (0x7b83ba4e)

Tags: wine, games, steam, git

I am trying to implement a patch fix for the addressed error in the title. I found the following wine-git patch that was said to address the issue:

https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/commitdiff/f529a5aaae85329f3a148943191be8bcbba2c51e

I found the directory in wine-git and opened the files in gedit and they all seem to already have these changes made. I am still encountering the error when I run Steam through Wine and try and play this particular game. Any help would be appreciated. Apologies in advance as you can probably tell I'm not a very experienced user of the OS, but I'm trying my best to learn and need some help, please. I can give whatever additional details are needed. Thank you

Comment: How did you install Wine? Compiling from the source you obtained from Git?

Comment: also, what game are you trying to run? and you do know steamOS is based on debian, right (and so is ubuntu)?

Comment: have you tried using a 32 bit prefix

Comment: @muru I installed wine through the software center. I don't know how to compile from the Git source.

Comment: @mchid I'm trying to run Rocket League through Steam. What does it being debian based mean for me? Does that mean I'm using an incompatible software for the OS? Sorry, I'm really really new at this.

Comment: actually, it should be compatable. I'll check into that game.

Comment: The version of Wine packaged for Ubuntu could be older than the patch and so might not have it. You'll have to compile Wine from source if you want to apply that patch. See http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-7ed3c3163e2b932ee2030a48f9c5e553dc41817b

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJXfV1-1N5U

Comment: @mchid The only thing that confuses me about this walkthrough is that to manually install the game through PlayOnLinux I have to have the setup.exe file and I don't know where to access that. I purchased the game through steam back when I had a functioning windows OS so can I access that file locally somehow? Thanks again!

Comment: What file do you have? You may need to right click on the file and select "extract here". Then the file may be in the extracted folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install play on linux.

Open play on linux.

Down on the lower left hand side of the window, click on "install a non-listed program".

Click next, click "install program in a new virtual drive" and then click next.

Make a name for the drive and then click next.

Click next again.

Click "32 bit windows installation" and then click next.

Wait a few minutes while wine updates.

Then, click browse.

Locate the setup.exe file and click "open".

Then click next.

Accept all the defaults.

Click on RocketLeague.exe to make a shortcut and then click next and select a name and click next and select "i don't want to make another shortcut" and click next.

Now, open play on linux and click on the RocketLeague shortcut and click "run".

---

**EDIT:**

To install STEAM just open play on linux and type steam and click on the steam installer. It's one of the preinstalled installers.

Comment: That's the thing. I have no setup file. I can only access the game through the steam client through wine and when I do it fails. Sorry I feel like I'm being a complete dunce by missing something rudimentary. I've searched the .wine directory and couldn't find anything in Program Files or Program Files (x84) that looked like a Rocket League setup file.Thank you for your efforts and I know this is definitely the right track. I'll keep searching

Comment: you can also run steam using play on linux

Comment: @CambrianCatalyst i think you just open play on linux and  type steam and click on the steam installer. It's one of the preinstalled installers.

Comment: This worked! And like all good problems the solution led me to another problem which is getting my usb xbox 360 controller to be recognized by the game =]. So glad to have taken a step forward finally though. Thank you so much!