# Rocket League won't run in Wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine, games, steam

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. As far as I know, I've satisfied all the needed dependencies to run Rocket League in Wine, but it doesn't seem to run. Here's my terminal output from opening Steam to attempting to run Rocket League.

```
buck@buck-linux ~ $ wine /mnt/5775d669-9265-436c-b7ac-1cbd206413c4/Wine/Steam/steam.exe
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.7.50 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please report bugs at http://bugs.wine-staging.com (instead of winehq.org).
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x32e480 (nil)): stub
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2015-08-28 18:13:31] Startup - updater built Aug 19 2015 11:28:52
[2015-08-28 18:13:32] Verifying installation...
[2015-08-28 18:13:32] Verification complete
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040ce8, 0x3f040ce0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d20, 0x3f040d18
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040cb0, 0x3f040ca8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d58, 0x3f040d50
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d90, 0x3f040d88
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:imm:ImmGetOpenStatus (0x1e40b0): semi-stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x32e244 (nil)): stub
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0x10094, 2, 0x32e854, 4) stub
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x110000 0 0x33fcdc 4 stub
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (3): stub
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x30e490 (nil)): stub
fixme:module:load_dll Loader redirect from L"wined3d.dll" to L"wined3d-csmt.dll"
fixme:winediag:wined3d_dll_init Experimental wined3d CSMT feature is currently enabled.
fixme:wbemprox:wbem_locator_ConnectServer unsupported flags
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7cf65728, 0x101e8328, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7cf65728
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_get__NewEnum 0x101e18c8, 0x4efe4fc
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_ProcessImageFileName 0x10216a78, L"D:\\Steam\\steam.exe"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Name 0x10216a78, L"Steam"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Enabled 0x10216a78, -1
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_Add 0x10216aa8, 0x10216a78
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {e2b3c97f-6ae1-41ac-817a-f6f92166d7dd} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {e2b3c97f-6ae1-41ac-817a-f6f92166d7dd} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:wbemprox:wbem_locator_ConnectServer unsupported flags
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7cf65728, 0x102a93d0, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7cf65728
fixme:advapi:StopTraceA (0, "Steam Event Tracing", 0x46fddd4) stub
fixme:advapi:StartTraceA (0x46fde60, "Steam Event Tracing", 0x46fddd4) stub
fixme:advapi:OpenTraceA 0x46fdc34: stub
fixme:advapi:EnableTrace (1, 0x10, 4, {22fb2cd6-0e7b-422b-a0c7-2fad1fd0e716}, cafe4242): stub
fixme:advapi:CloseTrace cafe4242: stub
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl The DISK_PARTITION_INFO and DISK_DETECTION_INFO structures will not be filled
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:dwrite:get_name_record_locale failed to get locale name for lcid=0x00000455
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl The DISK_PARTITION_INFO and DISK_DETECTION_INFO structures will not be filled
fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl The DISK_PARTITION_INFO and DISK_DETECTION_INFO structures will not be filled
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl The DISK_PARTITION_INFO and DISK_DETECTION_INFO structures will not be filled
fixme:thread:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 56, 0x33f7a4, (nil) 0x33f7a8
fixme:advapi:ProcessTrace 0x510b188 1 (nil) (nil): stub
fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0x33f694 0x00000ff0 0x33f6d0) Stub!
[0828/181332:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(173)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x33f7dc, overlapped 0x1975a0): stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x197e59c (nil)): stub
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x100a8, filter=0x33f7e8,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x100a8, filter=0x33f7e8,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x1e4046c, overlapped 0x1e40470): stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationA (hwnd=0x100b6, filter=0x562e4ec,flags=0x00000004) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33fb98 (nil)): stub
fixme:dwrite:dwritefactory_CreateMonitorRenderingParams (0x1): monitor setting ignored
[2015-08-28 18:13:33] Background update loop checking for update. . .
[2015-08-28 18:13:33] Checking for available update...
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {77f10cf0-3db5-4966-b520-b7c54fd35ed6} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {77f10cf0-3db5-4966-b520-b7c54fd35ed6} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x100b8, 0x1038d388): stub
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationA (hwnd=0x100cc, filter=0x32e3cc,flags=0x00000004) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:d3d:init_driver_info Unhandled OS version 6.3, reporting Win 8.
IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x10126, filter=0x68be92c,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x20126, filter=0x68be92c,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, hwnd=(nil)): stub
fixme:appbar:SHAppBarMessage unknown msg: 4
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=3): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=1): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=0): stub
fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR, hwnd=(nil), edge=2): stub
Refresh rate: 60
Refresh rate: 60
fixme:file:SetFileCompletionNotificationModes 0x208 1 - stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x100ae390, 0x12483660, {3dada31d-19ef-4dc1-b345-037927193422}, 1, 0x1243c974, (null), (null), 0x12483678): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Refresh rate: 60
Refresh rate: 60
Refresh rate: 60
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x110000 0 0x33fcdc 4 stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33fb98 (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040ce8, 0x3f040ce0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d20, 0x3f040d18
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040cb0, 0x3f040ca8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d58, 0x3f040d50
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d90, 0x3f040d88
Refresh rate: 15
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f004 (nil)): stub
Refresh rate: 60
Refresh rate: 1
fixme:d3d:init_driver_info Unhandled OS version 6.3, reporting Win 8.
IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.fixme:module:load_dll Loader redirect from L"wined3d.dll" to L"wined3d-csmt.dll"
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x2341b80, 0x23e73a0, 0x23e7398
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x2341b80, 0x23e73d8, 0x23e73d0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x2341b80, 0x23e7368, 0x23e7360
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x2341b80, 0x23e7410, 0x23e7408
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x2341b80, 0x23e7448, 0x23e7440
fixme:imm:ImmGetOpenStatus (0x175b00): semi-stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x20cef5c (nil)): stub
fixme:winediag:wined3d_dll_init Experimental wined3d CSMT feature is currently enabled.
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040ce8, 0x3f040ce0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d20, 0x3f040d18
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040cb0, 0x3f040ca8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d58, 0x3f040d50
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f006c50, 0x3f040d90, 0x3f040d88
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
Warning, Unknown language extension . Defaulting to INT
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 252950
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198029995678 [API loaded no]
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x20ce0f4 (nil)): stub
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_get__NewEnum 0x1154c8, 0x79e354
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_ProcessImageFileName 0x115510, L"D:\\Steam\\steam.exe"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Name 0x115510, L"Steam"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Enabled 0x115510, -1
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_Add 0x1154c8, 0x115510
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {e2b3c97f-6ae1-41ac-817a-f6f92166d7dd} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {e2b3c97f-6ae1-41ac-817a-f6f92166d7dd} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:advapi:StopTraceA (0, "Steam Event Tracing", 0x79e094) stub
fixme:advapi:StartTraceA (0x79e120, "Steam Event Tracing", 0x79e094) stub
fixme:advapi:OpenTraceA 0x79def4: stub
fixme:advapi:EnableTrace (1, 0x10, 4, {22fb2cd6-0e7b-422b-a0c7-2fad1fd0e716}, cafe4242): stub
fixme:advapi:CloseTrace cafe4242: stub
fixme:advapi:ProcessTrace 0x101eb188 1 (nil) (nil): stub
fixme:gameux:GameExplorerImpl_VerifyAccess (0x7dfc828, L"D:\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\rocketleague\\Binaries\\Win32\\RocketLeague.exe", 0x20cf2e0)
fixme:d3d:init_driver_info Unhandled OS version 6.3, reporting Win 8.
fixme:d3d11:D3D11CoreCreateDevice Ignoring feature levels.
fixme:dxgi:dxgi_device_init Ignoring adapter type.
fixme:d3d11:device_parent_create_swapchain_surface device_parent 0x7dfd258, container_parent 0x7e267e0, wined3d_desc 0x20cf018, surface 0x20cf000 partial stub!
fixme:d3d11:device_parent_create_swapchain_surface Implement DXGI<->wined3d usage conversion
fixme:d3d11:d3d11_device_GetFeatureLevel iface 0x7dfd240 stub!
fixme:d3d11:d3d11_device_GetImmediateContext iface 0x7dfd240, immediate_context 0x20cf688 stub!
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation (0x00000067,0x832e22c,0x00000008,(nil)) stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation (0x00000007,0x832e1c4,0x00000018,(nil)) stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation (0x0000005a,0x832e1dc,0x00000020,(nil)) stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation (0x00000032,0x832e238,0x00000004,(nil)) stub
fixme:dbghelp:validate_addr64 Unsupported address fffffffff72f0000
fixme:dbghelp:validate_addr64 Unsupported address fffffffff75a0000
fixme:dbghelp:validate_addr64 Unsupported address fffffffff72b0000
fixme:dbghelp:validate_addr64 Unsupported address fffffffff7280000
fixme:dbghelp:validate_addr64 Unsupported address fffffffff7220000
fixme:dbghelp:validate_addr64 Unsupported address fffffffff7050000
fixme:dbghelp:validate_addr64 Unsupported address fffffffff70c0000
fixme:faultrep:ReportFault 0x20cf188 0x0 stub
fixme:msvcrt:MSVCRT__set_abort_behavior _WRITE_CALL_REPORTFAULT unhandled
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext ((nil), (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
```

I'm running Wine 1.7.5 with Staging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wine Steam Error: Unhandled exception: unimplemented function x3daudio1\_7.dll.X3DAudioInitialize called in 32-bit code (0x7b83ba4e)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/664687/wine-steam-error-unhandled-exception-unimplemented-function-x3daudio1-7-dll-x3)

Comment: use playonlinux to install steam instead of wine. see the bottom of this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/664687/wine-steam-error-unhandled-exception-unimplemented-function-x3daudio1-7-dll-x3

Comment: Thanks for giving me that answer for PlayOnLinux, but my problem with POL is that it will install to my home folder, which I don't want. I have a 1TB drive for installing games, and Wine already has it configured as a drive. Do I just have to use symlinks to get my POL drives to that hard drive? If so, how do?

Comment: make a partition for pol and mount it at ~/.PlayOnLinux

Comment: can anything else be on that partition or does it have to be specifically for PlayOnlInux?

Comment: idk i think it might cause issues, just create a new partition and then move the contents of ~/.PlayOnLinux to the partition and unmount the partition and then mount the partition at ~/.PlayOnLinux. Finally, make an entry in /etc/fstab so that it mounts at boot.

Comment: is your 1tb drive NTFS by chance?

Comment: Yes and no. It's a 2tb drive divided in half to Ext4 and NTFS. NTFS is used for Windows and not mounted in Linux. I mount the Ext4 partition at boot.

Comment: okay, because ntfs mounts as no-exec

Comment: What problems would mounting an already-existing partition to ~/.PlayOnLinux cause?